# Questions about using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I'm trying to learn more about regex and I'm running into a block

my current query:

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {
 return str.match(/[0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}/g)? true : false
}
```

This will only work for a specific inputs such as `"555-555-5555"`, but for other inputs such as `"1 (555) 555-5555"` it will not. I'm at a loss on how to query for optional characters and whitespace. Moreover bracket handling is odd and I've found some crazy queries such as `/(\d+-)\1\d{4}/g` but I have no idea what its doing and I don't want to use code I don't understand.

Can someone show me a query that solves for "1 (555) 555-5555" where the first two characters (the one and space) are optional inputs?

These are inputs that the regex should be able to handle:

"1 (555) 555-5555"

"1(555)555-5555"

"1 555-555-5555"

"555-555-5555"

"(555)555-5555"

"5555555555"

I found a solution

```
regex: function telephoneCheck(str) {
   var regex = /^(1\s?)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[\s\-]?\d{3}[\s\-]?\d{4}$/;
   return regex.test(str);
}
telephoneCheck("555-555-5555");
```

But I have no idea whats going on in here. If someone could explain whats happening I'd be happy to give you the answer for this posted question :)

Comment: and what was the question? including optional spaces? where? what are the patterns?

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a general primer on regular expressions, but unfortunately this site isn't well suited to that kind of inquiry.

Comment: There is something called `{lower bound, upper bound}` in regex which is very good start in your case

Comment: @revo sorry, I edited the post to include a more specific question. I want to see an example of handling the input `"1 (555) 555-5555"` where the first two characters are optional while also allowing input for dashes in place of the brackets.

Comment: Although you may find an answer for latter use case, you can't simply combine it with your old regex. You should be clear about all accepted inputs.

Comment: optional characters are followed by `?`. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is great for helping understand difficult regex strings.

Comment: What about `(555)5555555`?

Comment: O'Reilly's Regular Expression Cookbook is a great reference that has this exact problem as an example. The regex they propose is broken down terminal by terminal: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s02.html

Comment: You updates are a variation on my original answer when you hadn't provided the extra strings. As said by @emisimpson92 the `?` is a conditional which means the character doesn't necessarily need to be there. The `\s` means white space.`[]` is a range. eg. `[xyz]` means *must* contain `x` or `y` or `z`. e.g. `/[xyz]/.test('zerba') //true` or `/[xyz]/.test('snake')` // false. Check out http://regex101.com it will really help you work out your expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have be wary of trying to be all things within regex and question why the data is so varied in the first place.

If you are just parsing a bunch of what you are thinking should be phone numbers for example and notice a lot of different formats it might actually be more readable to use logic.

There is probably a really clever way of doing the above but I tend to be a bit more brute force with regex until I need more.

The below combines both patterns in to one regex expression. You use the `|` separator to say `or`. Also if your strings are exactly as you say, you should to use the `^` (starts with) and `$` ends with to ensure you don't get false positives.

```
var pattern = /^[0-9] \([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$|^[0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}$/

pattern.test('555-555-5555') //true
pattern.test('1 (555) 555-5555') // true
pattern.test('(555) 555-5555') // false
```

And as I say if you have lots of different formats in one. Question why, is there a way to clean things up first. Then perhaps use logic and separate statements.

```
var parensPattern = /^[0-9] \([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/
var noParensPattern = /^[0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}$/
if(parensPattern.test('1 (555) 555-5555')) {
     // do something
} else if (noParensPattern.test('555-555-5555)) {
     // do something
}
```

Check out http://regex101.com, it is a great resource.